# Join Orders, Staff's first and last name, item and location MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join

Join Orders, Staff's first and last name, item and location into one so I can export the content into an Excel spreadsheet.

```
SELECT orders.order_id, staff.staff_id, staff.first_name, staff.last_name, items.name, locations.address1, locations.address2, locations.state,     locations.zip_code, orders.created_at
FROM orders
INNER JOIN staff
ON orders.staff_id = staff.staff_id
INNER JOIN items
ON orders.item_id = items.item_id
INNER JOIN location_staff
ON location_staff.staff_id = staff.staff_id
INNER JOIN locations
ON location_staff.loc_id = location.loc_id
```

I am trying to gather this information to put into an excel document but my query is not returning any results. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is An ERD diagram for further understanding

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7inma4s42xq5t4a/ERD.jpg

(Location_staff_link was shortened when created to location_staff)

Comment: I find it odd that you think there can be only one item per order. Usually there is an OrderItems table with the details about the items that were ordered.

Comment: I have designed it so that a staff member can choose one item only. which was part of the requirements of the client

Answer (score 0):

jsut remove the extra tables in your `FROM` clause,

```
SELECT orders.order_id, 
       staff.staff_id, 
       staff.first_name, 
       staff.last_name, 
       items.name, 
       orders.created_at 
FROM   orders 
       INNER JOIN staff 
               ON orders.staff_id = staff.staff_id 
       INNER JOIN items 
               ON orders.item_id = items.item_id 
       INNER JOIN locations 
               ON location.staff_id = staff.staff_id
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your query looks bad, so here is what I suggest to find the answer in this sort of case.

First reduce to the bare minimum of the first join and change the fields to select * (temporarily, you can go back to the real fields as soon as you find the issue) so you can se all the data.

Do you get records, then  add in any where clauses on the tables in that join. Do you still get records?

Then add in each join and each where clause one at a time until you find the one where the records disappear. This will tell you what you need to do to fix it.

Often in a case like this where no records are returned, one of the joins needs to be a left join or there is no data that meets the terms of the where clauses or one of the joins is improperly defined. And sometimes, there is a problem in that your database does not have the data you were expecting it to have. But first you have to use the process above to diagnose where the problem is.

Comment: Will do thanks. I was thinking surely somewhere down the line an inner join would not be appropriate.

Comment: I keep getting results until I add in the locations part. It worked fine joining (orders, staff and items) but then when I added locations no results..

Comment: So look in the locations table and see what the data looks like there. And look in the locations staff table to ensure the location id is being populated.